# Cassandra simple query runs very slow

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm running Cassandra 2.0.9 on 3 Amazon m3.Large instances.

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACE test;

CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '2'
};
```

Table:

```
cqlsh:test> DESCRIBE TABLE link_list;

    CREATE TABLE link_list (
      url text,
      visited boolean,
      PRIMARY KEY ((url))
    ) WITH
      bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
      caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
      comment='' AND
      dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
      gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
      index_interval=128 AND
      read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
      replicate_on_write='true' AND
      populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
      default_time_to_live=0 AND
      speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
      memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
      compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
      compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM link_list WHERE visited = False Limit 1;
```

The table has about 275,000 rows which is not much. There are about 20 clients trying to run this query and insert data to the link_list table. There are moments when everything runs smoothly but most of the time it takes couple of seconds to run the select query (with consistency two).

I have an index on the `visited` column and I would expect this query to run blazing fast on my setup but it's not the case. Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong and what is the best way to speed everything up.

Tracing (over 4k lines): http://www.pastebin.ca/2834424

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lines like this:

`Read 3 live and 3938 tombstoned cells | 16:06:46,644 |  54.228.94.22 |         138436`

offer a hint as to the reason. You are obviously deleting a lot of records (or using TTLs inappropriately), which is producing tombstones. Your tombstones all have to be read for this query, because otherwise Cassandra doesn't know what's been deleted.  Doing lots of deletes is an anti-pattern in Cassandra, for this reason.

Comment: I'm actually not doing any deletes. The only thing which comes to my mind is INSERT with IF NOT EXISTS. Does it generate the delete behaviour?

Comment: Do you ever insert nulls for unused columns (for example to make use of a generic prepared statement)? If so, you're creating tombstones.

Comment: I can confirm that the only thing I'm inserting is ("[url]", False). I also update the boolean to True WHERE url = [url].

Comment: Ok, well somewhere something is getting deleted. It's lurking in your code, waiting to be found. The presence of tombstones is sufficient evidence of this.

Comment: Oh, and why do you need IF NOT EXISTS? Inserts in Cassandra are idempotent.

Comment: I didn't want to override the visited column but now I know I was using Cassandra in an incorrect way. The tombstoned cells where populated by updating visited column (which had secondary index). I moved some logic to RabbitMQ and now everything flies.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to re-think your data model in this instance.  Here is an excerpt from the DataStax doc titled "[When to use an index](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html)":

> [C]reating an index on an extremely low-cardinality column, **such as a
>   boolean column**, does not make sense. Each value in the index becomes a
>   single row in the index, resulting in a huge row for all the false
>   values, for example. Indexing a multitude of indexed columns having
>   foo = true and foo = false is not useful.

One possible way to improve this scenario, would be to keep a separate table for links that have been visited.  When a link is visited, you have your application add that link's data to the new table, instead of updating the `link_list` table.  That way, you will know definitively if a link has been visited or not.

Comment: +1 for mention of extremely low cardinality. It's worth saying that low cardinality is critical, but there is a balance.

Comment: @rs_atl Exactly.  I try not to use secondary indexes at all, if I can help it.  But when I do, I've found that going with a "middle of the road" approach to cardinality usually yields the best results.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent suggestion on updating my data model. I didn't think about 2nd table.

Comment: I have a question about your suggestion. I'm assuming I don't delete rows from the "not visited" table. The question is how do I pull links which haven't been visited yet?

Comment: @LukaszKujawa Right...I'm not sure that a "not visited" table would work very well.  And likewise, Cassandra doesn't have a mechanism for querying by "NOT."  You could certainly query the visited links table for a specific URL (to determine if it has been visited or not), but querying for all URLs not visited might take some creative problem solving.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 Out of curiousity how would you map the unvisited links, since the query is to find all unvisisted, which is set[all] - set[visited] which perhaps requires too much lookup, and having a set[unvisited] seems a bad idea, since that would create too many deletes over time.

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen Non-existence is a difficult type of problem to solve with Cassandra by itself.  One way would be to use a large data analysis tool like Spark, and then it would be a simple matter of a SQL query.  Other than that, you could try computing set[unvisited] client-side, but I can't imagine that would perform well.  The best option here might be to use a datastore technology that is better-suited to this type of problem.